# Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedContent to model type after deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco8

(this is [a cross-post from the umbraco forum](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/100413-cannot-bind-source-content-type-umbracowebpublishedcachenucachepublishedcontent-to-model-type-foopublishedcontentmodelshome).)

I've built a site and it all works fine locally. I've just deployed my site to Azure, and published my database using SSMS' Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database feature. Both completed successfully. I can log into umbraco and see all the content I had locally on the Azure site but when I try to hit the homepage I get a YSOD with the error below.

I can log into the CMS and see all my content.

What's happening? What am I missing?

Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedContent to model type Foo.PublishedContentModels.Home.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingException: Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedContent to model type Foo.PublishedContentModels.Home.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[ModelBindingException: Cannot bind source content type Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.NuCache.PublishedContent to model type Foo.PublishedContentModels.Home.]
   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ContentModelBinder.ThrowModelBindingException(Boolean sourceContent, Boolean modelContent, Type sourceType, Type modelType) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Mvc\ContentModelBinder.cs:159
   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ContentModelBinder.BindModel(Object source, Type modelType) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Mvc\ContentModelBinder.cs:94
   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Mvc\UmbracoViewPageOfTModel.cs:152
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   Umbraco.Web.Mvc.ProfilingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) in D:\a\1\s\src\Umbraco.Web\Mvc\ProfilingView.cs:25
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'd done is disabled modelsBuilder with a config transform going to Azure without realizing this disables the Model *Binder* as well as Model *Builder*:

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="false" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
```

What I really wanted to do was leave `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable == true`  and set `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode == Nothing`:

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Nothing" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
```

This works as expected.